# XMLHttpRequest returns null when loading Malayalam XML file in iOS 7 Mobile Safari

Tags: safari, mobile-safari, javascript

I want to load a xml file with Malayalam text to mobile safari running in iOS 7. I'm using the below mentioned code to load a "Malayalam" xml from the local filesystem. The same Malayalam xml loads in iOS 5 and iOS 6 perfectly. But the Malayalam xml fails to load in iOS 7 mobile safari where xml files containing "English" text works fine with this code in the same iOS7.

```
function getXMLDoc(url, result) {

   var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

   try{

     request.open("GET", url, true);
     request.send();

     request.onreadystatechange = function() {

     if (request.readyState == 4) {

        console.log(request);
        result(request.responseXML);

     }
   }

 }
 catch (e) {
    console.log("getXmlDoc err:" + e.msg);
 }
```

}

the variable url is a relative path (data/malayalam.xml).

I have no idea why it returns null only when loading xml with Malayalam text. Please help.

Comment: have you fixed the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by dividing the big xml file into chunks and loaded one by one when needed.